# can I set a MAX Limit to a BIGINT cassandra's data type?

Tags: database-recommendation, cassandra

can I set a MAX Limit to a BIGINT cassandra data type?
this is my first step in cassandra db.
for example: bigint(10) just like in mysql?

Comment: MySQL's `bigint (10)` has no restrictions on the size of the numbers. It's the same as `bigint`, 8-byte integers.

Answer (score 1):

No. A Bigint is just a 64-bit signed long. No size or space limits can be specified. 
https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cql/types.html

Comment: Theirs docs have `DECIMAL` as a type option. Could this be used, for example with `DECIMAL(8,0)`? Or I am totally off?

Comment: And also: does Cassandra have `CHECK` constraints?